# How to pass an object into a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form in HTML where there is a field that has the ID attribute of Field 1, where the value is taken and assigned to variable Field1 that then gets fed into the var template.

I create a new date object and assign it to the var creationTime and I need to pass this also into the var template. How can I achieve this? The code below does not work...

```
$(function () {
$('#DownloadButton').click(update);
});

var creationTime = new Date();

var template = [
'<Field1><?Field1?></Field1>',
'<creationtime><?creationTime?></creationTime>',

 ].join('\r\n');

function update() {
  var variables = {

'Field1': $('#Field1').val(),
};

 var newXml = template.replace(/<\?(\w+)\?>/g,
function(match, name) {
  return variables[name];
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `creationTime` inside `variables` object where your replace function does lookup.

```js
$(function () {
$('#DownloadButton').click(function() {
    console.log(update())
  });
});

var template = [
'<Field1><?Field1?></Field1>',
'<creationtime><?creationTime?></creationTime>',

 ].join('\r\n');

function update() {
  var variables = {
    'Field1': $('#Field1').val(),
    creationTime: new Date
  };

 return template.replace(/<\?(\w+)\?>/g, function(match, name) { return variables[name];});
}

console.log(update())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Field1">
<button id="DownloadButton">DownloadButton</button>
```

Comment: Hi, this looks good but if I put in the desired format - YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ it returns invalid?

Comment: @Porkball21 Could you be more specific? How do you format date? Which part of the code "returns invalid"?

Comment: creationTime: new Date(YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ)

and the '<creationtime><?creationTime?></creationTime>', returns invalid date within the tags

but if I remove the format required it displays the date fine within the tags

Comment: `new Date` creates new date it doesn't format anything. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). You may use [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) to format date. Or if you already have formatted string pass it as-is.